# Can't modify variable from params inside model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code inside model:

```
def self.price(start=0, stop=100_000_000)
  where "price >= ? AND price <= ?",
    "#{start} ".delete(' '), "#{stop} ".delete(' ')
end
```

And the following in controller:

```
def index
  @businesses = Business.price(params[:price_from], params[:price_to])
end
```

For example, when `params[:price_from]` equals `'30 000'`, last space inside `"#{start} ".delete(' ')` is deleted, but I can't delete the space between digits and get

```
PG::InvalidTextRepresentation: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "30 000"
```

I tried different approaches, like

```
#{start} ".gsub(/\s+/, '')
#{start} ".split.join
```

Cloning `start` doesn't help. What should I do?

Comment: why you have given space after `#{start}`

Comment: To show that .delete(' ') actually works, but doesn't delete that nasty space in `start` value

Comment: `#{start.to_s.gsub(" ","")}` try this

Comment: @test same error. Maybe it has smth to do with utf-8?

Comment: I have edited my comment..please check

Comment: query will be 

`def self.price(start=0, stop=100_000_000)
  where "price >= ? AND price <= ?",
    "#{start.to_s.gsub(" ","")}", "#{stop}.to_s.gsub(" ","")"
end`

Comment: @test You meant `"#{start.to_s.gsub(' ','')}", "#{stop.to_s.gsub(' ','')}"` ? Same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81498/discussion-between-test-and-leemour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that space was a **non-breaking space**.
It was found using `start[2].ord` which returned `160` for `30 000`.
The space was generated by JS `toLocaleString` function when formatting values in browser.